# Looking for a command that returns a value with the number of cells with content

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice Calc, if that makes a difference.

I'm looking for a command that returns a value after looking over a column and seeing how many cells have content in it.

ie. I have a column,`D`, of 10 rows -  how do I return a value of how many of those rows have a number in it?

Comment: You can use COUNTIF to select non-blank cells (see https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/#countif-blank). But note that questions about general usage of Excel are more suited to SuperUser (http://superuser.com/)

Comment: for not quite programming questions you can look for http://superuser.com/

Comment: As Jean points out, this belongs to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

=[COUNT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Statistical_Functions_Part_One#COUNT)(D1:D10)

An alternative without a function is to set the field immediately to the left of the zoom slider to Count and observe the value there when D1:D10 is selected.